# Chrome Driver does not start with preconfigured extensions when launched using WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I have to verify some ads displayed on google search. These ads displayed only when I install the extensions for chrome browser. But when I launch chrome browser from WebDriver script it launches the browser without extentions (even though extensions are already installed) to chrome browser.

I have googled but didnt get much information.

I have tried below method but it didnt work out:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "libs\\chromedriver.exe");               
capability.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--load-extension=C:\\Users\\ashfaq.md\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions"));
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn how to install Chrome Extensions via ChromeDriver here:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions

Answer (score 0):

Though not tested on own end... Please check the following:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
 options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"))
 options.setBinary(new File("/path/to/chrome"));

 // For use with ChromeDriver:
 ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

 // or alternatively:
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
 ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

 // For use with RemoteWebDriver:
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
 RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
     new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```